# Jquery .load(), filling of input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I would load a html (in file :/retc.html) :
`<input id="x" type="text" name="number" value="" size="5" />`

to html div on another page:
`<div id="property"></div>`

I would fill value in the input after load.

I am using this script in onclick function:

`$("#property").load("/rect.html");
$('#x').val("5");`

Loading of the input is OK, but the value is not filled. The value flashes in input only. Where is the problem?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the callback argument of the `load` function -

```
$("#property").load("/rect.html",function() {
    $('#x').val("5");
});
```

That should ensure the text box is available on the page before you try to populate it.